# Adding two Variables together?

Tags: javascript, variables

Trying to add two integer variables together, however, I can't seem to figure it out as it just joins them as strings?

```
var age_child = 10;
var age_gap = 10
alert(age_child+age_gap);
```

Result: 1010,
Want Result: 20

Comment: Not reproducible: http://jsfiddle.net/VH9jU/ Please clarify your question and provide the code which you actually use.

Comment: Note that data from the `.value` of a form field is always a String and never a Number, even if it just contains digits

Comment: Your code in the question does not reproduce the problem you have stated you have. This is a problem often seen when dealing with values obtained from the DOM. Thus, your question would be useful if you [edit]ed it to actually reproduce the stated problem (e.g. use a snippet to add some HTML from which you obtain a `.value`). As it is, this question is not very useful.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
var age_child = parseInt(10);
var age_gap = parseInt(10);

alert(age_child+age_gap); // should now alert 20
```

To clarify, in this exact example it is not required to do `parseInt`. However, I assumed you didn't exactly have `10` in your code either and they're instead variables.

Comment: Don't forget to pass the the **radix** as second parameter. But in this specific case, using `parseInt` is unnecessary.

Answer (score 8):

**use**
`parseInt(age_child) + parseInt(age_gap);`

Answer (score 0):

```
let x = 5;
let y = 10;
let sum = x + y;

console.log('The sum of x and y is: ' + sum);
```