# Can't add together two variables which store an offsetHeight

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to add two numbers together so I can use a CSS calc function to reduce the top margin of an element so it shows just the title and its top line text.

```
 var roomInfoPanel = document.querySelector(".room-info");
 var panelCapacityInfo = parseInt(document.querySelector(".room-info__capacity").offsetHeight);
 var panelTitleRoom = parseInt(document.querySelector(".room-info__title").offsetHeight);

 var panelCombinedHeights = panelCapacityInfo + panelTitleRoom;

 if (panelTitleRoom && panelCapacityInfo) {
    document.querySelector(".room-info").style.marginTop = "calc( -" + panelCombinedHeights + "-7vw + -20px)";
 }
```

However, `panelCombinedHeights`  always returns undefined :(

I don't think this is a scope issue.

The `parseInt` was added after looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7658176/adding-two-variables-together) article, but without this no good either.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to convert variables to numbers

```js
var roomInfoPanel = document.querySelector(".room-info");
 var panelCapacityInfo = parseInt(document.querySelector(".room-info__capacity").offsetHeight);
 var panelTitleRoom = parseInt(document.querySelector(".room-info__title").offsetHeight);

 // Convert variables to numbers
 // Print what to summ
 console.log(panelCapacityInfo, panelTitleRoom)
 var panelCombinedHeights = Number(panelCapacityInfo) + Number(panelTitleRoom);
 // Print summ
 console.log(panelCombinedHeights)

 if (panelTitleRoom && panelCapacityInfo) {
    console.log("Style to be applied:", "calc( -" + panelCombinedHeights + "-7vw + -20px)");
    document.querySelector(".room-info").style.marginTop = "calc( -" + panelCombinedHeights + "-7vw + -20px)";
 }
```

```css
.room-info {
  height: 200px;
}
.room-info__capacity {
  height: 100px;
}
.room-info__title {
  height: 70px;
}
```

```html
<div class="room-info">
<div class="room-info__capacity">
1
</div>
<div class="room-info__title">
2
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sadly, no change I am afraid :(

Comment: Check my answer, press "Run code snippet" - everything works, maybe problem not in adding together two variables?

Answer (score 0):

The function `offsetHeigth` already returns a number, so you don't need the `parseInt()` here.

Are the values `panelCapacityInfo`  and `panelTitleRoom`  defined or not?

If they are undefined then the error is probably in the querySelector.

Comment: They are yes. The console shows they return a number.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var roomInfoPanel = document.querySelector(".room-info");
 var panelCapacityInfo = parseInt(document.querySelector(".room-info__capacity").offsetHeight);
 var panelTitleRoom = parseInt(document.querySelector(".room-info__title").offsetHeight);

 var panelCombinedHeights = parseInt(panelCapacityInfo) + parseInt(panelCapacityInfo)

 if (panelTitleRoom && panelCapacityInfo) {
    document.querySelector(".room-info").style.marginTop = "calc( -" + panelCombinedHeights + "-7vw + -20px)";
 }
```